# Why the height of an element is different from the total height of its children

Tags: javascript

When I try to sum the `height` of the children of an element, the result is different from the element actual height, I can't figured out how calculate the sum accurately.

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container');

var containerHeight = container.getBoundingClientRect().height;

var childrenTotalHeight = Array.from(container.children).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.getBoundingClientRect().height, 0);

console.log({
  containerHeight, 
  childrenTotalHeight
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <p>world</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a guess: Margins between the children?

Comment: That's correct, is there a way to include margin? I can't rely on the style because it may return different units (px, rem, em...) and I don't want to deal with margin collapsing.